# IControllerModelConvention with dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a website using asp.net core 2.0 MVC.
I have come across a situation where I would like to apply different authorization filters to different controllers based on some logic. For example, all controllers starting with a prefix `Identity` would have one authorization filter run, while all other controllers would have another authorization filter run.

I followed [this article](https://joonasw.net/view/apply-authz-by-default) showing that this can be done by adding an `IControllerModelConvention` implementation to the `services.addMvc(options)` method like below during startup in the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new MyAuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention());
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(MyOtherFilterThatShouldBeAppliedGlobally));
}
```

And here is the class `MyAuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention` where you can see I am adding a specifc authorize filter to every controller based on a naming convention.

```
public class AddAuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        if (controller.ControllerName.StartsWith("Identity"))
        {
            controller.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(...));

            // This doesn't work because controller.Filters 
            // is an IList<IFilterMetadata> rather than a FilterCollection
            controller.Filters.Add(typeof(AnotherFilter)); 
        }
        else
        {
            controller.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(...));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is I cannot add filters in this way using the `typeof(filter)` overload like I could during startup in the `ConfigureServices` method. I require this because some of the filters I want to add require dependency injection to instantiate them.

My question is how can I achieve this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you tried adding the filters to the DI container?

Comment: @Brad I have added the filters to the DI container. That is not the problem here. The problem is the method in which filters can be added to a controller. The `Filters` property only accepts instances of the filters rather than accepting a `Type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
controller.Filters.Add(new TypeFilterAttribute(typeof(AnotherFilter)));
```